# How I can start with ASP.NET and Sharepoint 2010 Development?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, web-part, asp.net, mvc

I don't know how I can begin with the Development for Sharepoint 2010. I can create ASP.NET Webapplications and begin with ASP.NET MVC 4 Now.

I search a good article for the work of ASP.NEt (MVC or not MVC) with Sharepoint 2010 or heigher. The article can be in engish or german. I search a article for beginner :/

Comment: For SharePoint solution development, you want to be looking at WebForms not MVC. (Apps in 2013 can be any web technology though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a .Net developer, you can get an idea of SharePoint using the following links,

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829215.aspx
2. http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2013/01/21/sharepoint-2010-development-overview.aspx
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/architecture-of-sharepoint-for-Asp-Net-developers/
4. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/The%2012%20factors%20to%20turn%20ASP.NET%20developers%20to%20SharePoint%202010.aspx

For working with Visual Studio to develop SharePoint solutions, refer the below URL's

1. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921(v=vs.100).aspx
2. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231568.aspx

Comment: i try to create a sharepoint application but if I want do start a empty sharepoint project I get a error that I need sharepoint server on my computer :( Can I install sharepoint 2010 of a vm and use this for testing?

Comment: Install SharePoint in your local machine and then try to create a project.